# Uploading a file through HTTPS port using httpsurlconnection class

Tags: android, security

I have a server that only opens a port using port number 443. I need to upload a file to that server using Android client. My question is:

is it possible to connect and upload to such server using httpsurlconnection or do i need to use other class?

if it is possible, can you please show me an example of it?

thanks.

Comment: At first google something and share what you have tried, please.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that simply by creating a URL with 'https' instead of 'http'.

Example from documentation:

```
URL url = new URL("https://www.android.com/");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
 InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
 readStream(in);
} finally {
 urlConnection.disconnect();
}
```

Refer to the documentation for details:

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html#HttpsExample
https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html